# Keycloak Silent Authentication

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a react app that uses Keycloak endpoint token_endpoint to authenticate the user. The problem I'm facing now is how to update/refresh this token. I know I could use a refresh token but that's a bad practice since has security issue when it comes to a web application. It seems to me that the best approach would be to use Silent Authentication.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any example or documentation that allows me to achieve this. In case you guys have another approach I'm open to suggestions.

Tks

Comment: What makes you think that using refresh tokens has a security issue? I suggest you searching references about this and not trusting in your mere hunch. OAuth is the most widely used securization protocol nowadays and it's very strong while using it with a proper secure transfer protocol altogether.

Comment: It's not a hunch... There's a lot of material explaining why it's a bad idea storing a refresh token in the browser (SPA). "Refresh Tokens are long-lived. This means when a client gets one from a server, this token must be stored securely to keep it from being used by potential attackers, for this reason, it is not safe to store them in the browser..." More info: https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/

Comment: If you don't trust in the browser for refresh tokens, then use a server-side adapter. That will generate you a browser cookie for the web session, which will be linked to access/refresh token tuples at server side. Still, keep in mind that if someone steals your cookie and it is long lived, he may hack your account. If you cannot trust your users in this, then you should try to minimize the damage that a hacker with some stolen token/cookie could do. But, as I say, most of the sites in the internet rely in browser storage for managing their sessions.

Answer (score 1):

It would consist just of providing the `prompt=none` parameter on the authentication request as stated in the OpenID Connect 1.0 Core spec:
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

> prompt OPTIONAL.
>
> Space delimited, case sensitive list of ASCII string
>   values that specifies whether the Authorization Server prompts the
>   End-User for reauthentication and consent. The defined values are:
>
> none
>
> The Authorization Server MUST NOT display any authentication or
>   consent user interface pages. An error is returned if an End-User is
>   not already authenticated or the Client does not have pre-configured
>   consent for the requested Claims or does not fulfill other conditions
>   for processing the request. The error code will typically be
>   login_required, interaction_required, or another code defined in
>   Section 3.1.2.6. This can be used as a method to check for existing
>   authentication and/or consent.

Comment: Hi Hans, not sure how this would work. Today I make a request to http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token to get my user authenticated. Then I receive the token, refresh token, etc. How could I renew my token based on this parameter `prompt=none` To witch endpoint should I send a request to get the renewed token?

Answer (score -1):

1. Authenticate to obtain an access_token with `/auth` (**prompt=login**).
2. Just call OIDC /token with `grant_type=refresh_token` to refresh token with the `access_token`. the new response include access_token, refresh_token and so.
3. After that you must update them for the new api calls.